# Categories not showing up in simulator... Stuck

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm trying to do a to-do list app that adds categories and items inside each category. The categories are saved in the realm database but it's not loading up at all. I revised my code like a and still nothing shows up at all. The tableview cell is clickable but the names aren't showing up on the screen. It is still saved in the realm file though. If someone knows the solution please help me and here's the code. any sort of help is appreciated

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
class CategoryViewController: UITableViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var categories: Results<Category>!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadCategories()
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textfield = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add new Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) {
            (action) in
            let newCategory = Category()
            newCategory.name = textfield.text!
            self.save(category: newCategory)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addTextField {
            (field) in
            textfield = field
            textfield.placeholder = "Add new Category"
        }
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToDoListViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    //MARK: - TableView DataSource Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath)
        let category = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = category.name
        return cell
    }

    //MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods
    func save(category: Category) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(category)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error saving category, \(error)")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadCategories() {
        categories = realm.objects(Category.self)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

And these are the Category and Item classes:...

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Category: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  let items = List<Item>()
}

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {
  dynamic var title: String = ""
  dynamic var done: Bool = false
  var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "items")
}
```

The below image is the situation of the app.

[image: App situation]

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: have you checked that you really are getting the results back that you expect?  if you print `category.name` as part of `cellForRowAt` what does it show you?

Comment: The problem is that its not showing up in the tableview simulator but it is still saved in the realm file.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it printed this

Comment: Results<Category> <0x7fb519f14770> (
 [0] Category {
  items = List<Item> <0x6000031fd0e0> (
  
  );
 },
 [1] Category {
  items = List<Item> <0x6000031fd180> (
  
  );
 },
 [2] Category {
  items = List<Item> <0x6000031fd220> (
  
  );
 }
)

Comment: ok, and if you print categories[indexPath.row].name ?

Comment: its not printing anything

Comment: then your problem is retrieving the data, and not the tableview...  check that you're actually getting the data back and then worry about the tableview.  in `loadCategories`, you could check the count, and print out some of the data,

Comment: what should i fix in my code?

Comment: The data is available. The problem is that the names aren't displaying in the tableview

Comment: do you want to continue in chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214650/categories-not-showing-up-in-simulator-stuck

Comment: i don't have enough reputation points

Comment: ok.  you need to check that the data actually exists where you think it does.  it's not enough just to know that you saved it there, you have to check you can retrieve it.  When  you think you have loaded the data, print out the number of elements, and either step through and print each name, or the first and last.  If that all works, then the problem is your tableview, but if you're not seeing anything there, it's the database and nothing to do with the tableview

Comment: well i used a print statement in the save function. i added a new category and that's what it printed:

Comment: Category {
 items = List<Item> <0x600000e85360> (
 
 );
}

Comment: not in the save, in the load, and don't just print out the the whole list, print out the element that you're trying to access.

Comment: i tried to print out the first element and that's what i got

Comment: Category {
 items = List<Item> <0x600002fa81e0> (
 
 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your realm object. The category object is defined like this

```
class Category: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  let items = List<Item>()
}
```

and it needs to be like this,

```
class Category: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
  let items = List<Item>()
}
```

adding the @objc marks the var as managed by Realm:

or like this

```
@objcMembers class Category: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  let items = List<Item>()
}
```

where @objcMembers makes all of the vars managed by Realm.

You'll need to update your Item Realm object as well.

Comment: well whenever i add @objc the app crashes when i run it.. i've tried this before as well

Comment: @ZiadM.Issa That is how Realm works and if the app is crashing, it's being caused by something else. But, 'app crashing' is a bit vague. Where is it crashing? What line? Is there an error message or log? My guess is that your podfile is outdated, wrong version of realm being used, old Xcode or settings, or your developer account is the wrong type. I would post a different question about the crash with those details, include the code, and once that's ironed out, revisit my answer as it will fix this problem the question outlines.

Comment: yeah it was indeed an outdated version of realmswift.. i reinstalled cocoapods and realmswift and its now working well. thank you very much